# problem with visual studio 2005 attach to process

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a problem with Visual studio 2005.
I have a problem with Attach to Process.
Every time I try to attach to process, my opened windows are closed (solution explorer window and output window), and many many other windows get opened (windows like object test bench, breakpoints, memory 1, memory 2, memory 3... watch 1, watch 2... geristers, modules, and many many more).
What can be the problem and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Visual Studio has two modes: edit mode and debugging mode. Each mode has its own window settings. When you change the settings for one mode it will remember it for that mode. So just attach, change the layout to your liking and you'll get it back when you attach again or debug.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Sebastiaan